# Can i run query right after "php artisan serve"

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

Hello i am beginner at framework laravel, but for my school project i have to connect my application to postgresql database, that i have done and i already displayed everything what i needed but i have about 20 milion rows in my database and doing just simple query which will display 25rows approx. like this takes atleast 5 seconds
`AUDI | 876 984
 FIAT | 756 867
 SEAT | 678 985
 FORD | 586 098
...............`

How can i store output of that query in some variable and then use it later for some calculations so i can run that 5 second query before doing something else(for example when i run php artisan server in cli) or is there a way to fasten up those 20 000 000 rows in tables(it would be awesome if you could provide some sample code for it too...i myself put it all in controller in one method and when button is pressed the controller returns view with output of query and then in one file it is printed with for loop)

This is example of my 
[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKon8.png)

```php
ProductControler extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        $things = DB::table('table')
                    ->select(array(as something1,as something2))
                    ->join some stuff
                    ->groupby some stuff
                    ->orderby  some stuff
                    ->get some stuff
        return view('layout.overview',compact('things'));
    }
}
-----------------------------------------------
in overview.blade.php is something like this
------------------------------------------------
@foreach($things as $thing)
    {{$thing->something1}}
    {{$thing->something2}}
@endforeach
-------------------------------------------------
and in routes something like this
------------------------------------------------
Route::get('products/', 'ProductControler@index');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by making custom command which i run before "php artisan serve" and it makes me new table with counted types of cars